# excel vba method workbook opened or closed true or false

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a method or perhaps an object in conjunction with a `applicaton.` method which when utilized will write in the log (on a range on a sheet) whether the workbook was opened or closed.

Instead of making two sub procedures, one log for opening and a log for closing, I am looking to combine both logs.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub workbook_open()

Call Unprot
Sheets("log").Activate
Range("A1").Value = "Workbook Opened"
Range("B1").Value = "User"
Range("C1").Value = "LAN ID"
Range("D1").Value = "Computer"
Range("E1").Value = "Domain"
Range("F1").Value = "Count"
Rows("2:2").Insert
Range("F2").Value = Sheets("log").Range("F2").Value + 1
Range("A2").Value = Now
Range("B2") = Application.UserName
Range("C2") = Environ$("username")
Range("D2") = Environ$("computername")
Range("E2") = Environ$("USERDOMAIN")
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Call Prot

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 Call Unprot
Sheets("log").Activate
Range("H1").Value = "Workbook Closed"
Range("I1").Value = "User"
Range("J1").Value = "LAN ID"
Range("K1").Value = "Computer"
Range("L1").Value = "Domain"
Range("M1").Value = "Count"
Rows("2:2").Insert
Range("M2").Value = Sheets("log").Range("M2").Value + 1
Range("H2").Value = Now
Range("I2") = Application.UserName
Range("J2") = Environ$("username")
Range("K2") = Environ$("computername")
Range("L2") = Environ$("USERDOMAIN")
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
Call Prot
End Sub
```

P.S. I believe I could condense this code to a for loop?

Comment: Since you want to record the **date/time** for both open and close, you need two macros.

Comment: Ah I didn't see the column differences.  But really I don't see much of a benefit to that.  Since the open/close will be on the heels of one other, they could be written sequentially instead of in parallel to the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code for writing to the log in a seperate subroutine or function and call the sub/function from both events. Use a variable to differentiate what action is being written to the log:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    call writeToLog "Workbook Closed"
End sub

Private Sub workbook_open()
    call writeToLog "Workbook Opened"
end sub


sub writeToLog(strAction as string)
    Call Unprot
    Sheets("log").Activate
    Range("H1").Value = strAction
    Range("I1").Value = "User"
    Range("J1").Value = "LAN ID"
    Range("K1").Value = "Computer"
    Range("L1").Value = "Domain"
    Range("M1").Value = "Count"
    Rows("2:2").Insert
    Range("M2").Value = Sheets("log").Range("M2").Value + 1
    Range("H2").Value = Now
    Range("I2") = Application.UserName
    Range("J2") = Environ$("username")
    Range("K2") = Environ$("computername")
    Range("L2") = Environ$("USERDOMAIN")
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Call Prot
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  Call Unprot
  writeLog "Workbook Opened"
  Call Prot

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

  Call Unprot
  writeLog "Workbook Closed"
  Call Prot

End Sub

Sub writeLog(openClose as String)

  With Sheets("log")
    Rows("2:2").Insert
    Range("A2").Value = Now()
    Range("B2") = Application.UserName
    Range("C2") = Environ$("username")
    Range("D2") = Environ$("computername")
    Range("E2") = Environ$("USERDOMAIN")
    Range("F2")= Sheets("log").Range("F2").Value + 1
    Range("G2").Value = openClose
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
  End With

End Sub
```

I wouldn't write that header each time.  Just write it manually once, there's really no value in using code to re-write it every time... unless you think people will overwrite.

A note: This code doesn't take into account when you will run out of page space.  Excel 2007 and higher is limited to just over a million rows so you have a lot of time, but if you're running 2003 you only have 64k+ rows, which can run out quickly, depending on usage.

**--EDIT--**

If you don't mind entries "stacking up" instead of being side-by-side, this will work.  Otherwise you have to build in an offset to move the data to the right, or have a second sub as Gary's Student mentions in the comments.